# How do i connect two nodes with a line

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How do I connect a node which lies in the first container to another node in the second container, i.e if i have a pane which has a sub node in it how will i connect it to another pane sub node, I've only manged to connect nodes that are is the same container but that's is not what i need, i want something like this.

```
enter code here
public class Main extends Application {

   static Pane root = new Pane();


   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

      Circuit c1 = new Circuit(10,10);
      Circuit c2 = new Circuit(200,10);
      Circuit c3 = new Circuit(10,200);
      Circuit c4 = new Circuit(200,200);

      root.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2, c3, c4);

      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
      primaryStage.show();
  }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
 }
```

The circuit Class

```
enter code here

 import static sample.Main.root;

 public class Circuit  extends Pane{

Circuit(int LOCATION_X, int LOCATION_Y){
    setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
    setPrefSize(150,150);

    setLayoutX(LOCATION_X);
    setLayoutY(LOCATION_Y);

    createCircle cir = new createCircle();

    cir.setLayoutX(75);
    cir.setLayoutY(75);

    // register handlers
    cir.setOnDragDetected(startHandler);
    cir.setOnMouseDragReleased(dragReleaseHandler);
    cir.setOnMouseDragEntered(dragEnteredHandler);

    // add info allowing to identify this node as drag source/target
    cir.setUserData(Boolean.TRUE);

    getChildren().add(cir);



    root.setOnMouseReleased(evt -> {
        // mouse released outside of a target -> remove line
        root.getChildren().remove(startHandler.line);
        startHandler.line = null;
    });
    root.setOnMouseDragged(evt -> {
        if (startHandler.line != null) {
            Node pickResult = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
            if (pickResult == null || pickResult.getUserData() != Boolean.TRUE) {
                // mouse outside of target -> set line end to mouse position
                startHandler.line.setEndX(evt.getX());
                startHandler.line.setEndY(evt.getY());
            }
        }
    });
}

    class DragStartHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

       public Line line;

       @Override
       public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
           if (line == null) {
               Node sourceNode = (Node) event.getSource();
               line = new Line();
               Bounds bounds = sourceNode.getBoundsInParent();

               // start line at center of node
               line.setStartX((bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getMaxX()) / 2);
               line.setStartY((bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getMaxY()) / 2);
               line.setEndX(line.getStartX());
               line.setEndY(line.getStartY());
               sourceNode.startFullDrag();
               root.getChildren().add(0, line);
           }
       }
   }

   DragStartHandler startHandler = new DragStartHandler();
   EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> dragReleaseHandler = evt -> {
       if (evt.getGestureSource() == evt.getSource()) {
           // remove line, if it starts and ends in the same node
           root.getChildren().remove(startHandler.line);
       }
       evt.consume();
       startHandler.line = null;
   };
   EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragEnteredHandler = evt -> {
       if (startHandler.line != null) {
           // snap line end to node center
           Node node = (Node) evt.getSource();
           Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInParent();
           startHandler.line.setEndX((bounds.getMinX()+bounds.getMaxX())/2); 

           startHandler.line.setEndY((bounds.getMinY()+bounds.getMaxY())/2);
        }
       };

 }
```

The point from where the wire will drawn out and connected to

```
enter code here

 public class createCircle extends Circle {

createCircle(){

   super(25, Color.BLACK.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Ultimately, the things you are connecting are in the same container (e.g. they are certainly both in the root of the scene), just not directly. Add the line to the common ancestor of the nodes you are connecting.

Comment: or add invisible pane over the top and draw a line there.

Comment: what do you mean by adding the line to the common ancestor? I want to connect sub node of pane to another, the common ancestor would be that main root added to the scene. the case is there would be multiple circuits like above and I must be able to detect which one the circuit is connected to.

Comment: @ShadyWatson Yes, exactly. Not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: @James_D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658505/javafx-connecting-two-child-nodes-with-a-line-by-dragging-and-dropping           
look at the answer, if I put each circle in a sperate container they won't connect

Comment: The only difference should be transforming the coordinates. If it's not working, you need to include the code you have tried. No one can diagnose what you are doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: @James_D sir would you kindly look at this piece of code, its not working at all, i don't what to do, the original code can be found in the link I mentioned in the comment section

Comment: Can you format that so it's easy to read? Each class in a separate code block, with the complete class formatted in each case.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing coordinate systems.

```
Bounds bounds = sourceNode.getBoundsInParent();
```

will give you the bounds of `sourceNode` in the coordinate system of the `sourceNode`'s parent, which is going to be the current `Circuit` instance (if I read your code correctly). However, you are using those bounds to calculate the coordinates of the line, which is placed in the root node, so you need the coordinates in the coordinate system of the root.

You can transform the coordinates by doing something like

```
Bounds boundsInScene = sourceNode.localToScene(sourceNode.getBoundsInLocal());
Bounds boundsInRoot = root.sceneToLocal(boundsInScene);
```

Now `boundsInRoot` represents the bounds of `sourceNode` in the coordinate system of `root`, so you can use it to compute the coordinates of the line. There are likely similar transforms you need to make throughout the code.

Comment: yes I can see the wires not but there is still something wrong with it, only from the last circuit can I drag the wire freely but it won't connect but when I drag the line from circuit 1 it automatically connects to circuit 2 and circuit 2 connects to circuit 3 while circuit 3 is dead.